# feting label time on the datepicker

Tags: ios, iphone, datepicker

I am working with the UIdatepicker. I am fetching the time from the datepicker and showing the date on the label. Once i select the date it is shown on the label and datepicker is hidden away. Now i want that when i call the picker it should show me the selection bar of the datepicker on the date of the label which i selected previously selected on the datepicker.Code i am using is shown below:-

```
-(void)datepickershown:(UILabel *)time animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select the Time" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:@"DONE" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
    pickdate = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:[actionsheet bounds]];
    pickdate.hidden = NO;
    //pickdate.date = [NSDate date];
    pickdate.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [pickdate addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDateInLabel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionsheet addSubview:pickdate];
    [actionsheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionsheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 500)];
    CGRect pickerRect = pickdate.bounds;
    pickerRect.origin.y = -90;
    pickdate.bounds = pickerRect;
}    

- (IBAction)changeDateInLabel:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"I Am Changing the values");
    df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
}
```

Image below  can describe you more

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use setDate:animated of UIDatePicker...

```
- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date animated:(BOOL)animated
```

to convert your label.text to NSDate:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"]; // depends on 12(hh) or 24(HH) 

NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:label.text];
```

Comment: i already used this but it is not showing me the desired result??